# Ошибка в GET-запросе

Tags: ajax

Вот  такой вот код, браузер выдает: "Ошибка Ajax: Not Found". Что неправильно в коде?

```
<!-- urlget.html -->
<html>
<head>
    <title> Пример использования Ajax с GET-запросом </title>
</head>

<body><center />
<h1>Загрузка веб-страницы в контейнер DIV</h1>
<div id="info"> Это предложение будет заменено </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function ajaxRequest()
{
    var r;
    try // Для всех браузеров, кроме ие
    {
        r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        try // ие6+
        {
            r = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            try // ie5
            {
                r = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e) // Браузер не поддерживает Ajax
            {
                r = false;
            }
        }
    }
return r;
}

nocache = "&nocache=" + Math.random()*1000000;
var request = ajaxRequest();
if(request)
{
    request.open("GET", "urlget.php?url=oreilly.com" + nocache, true)

    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(this.readyState == 4)
        {
            if(this.status == 200)
            {
                if(this.responseText != null)
                {
                    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 
                    this.responseText
                }
                else alert("Ошибка Ajax: Данные не получены")
            }
        else alert("Ошибка Ajax: " + this.statusText)
        }
    }
    request.send(null)
}
else 
{
    alert("Ошибка: Ваш браузер не поддерживает AJAX")
}
</script></body></html>
```

Comment: повтор вопроса: [Не работает Ajax-вызов](http://hashcode.ru/questions/117630/не-работает-ajax-вызов)

Comment: Не, это не повтор, там был запрос POST, а тут GET.

Comment: Вопрос снят, проблема была в пхп-файле.

Answer (score 1):

```
request.open("GET", "urlget.php?url=oreilly.com" + nocache, true)
```

Попробуйте изменить адрес к которому обращаетесь, к примеру просто oreilly.com:

```
request.open("GET", "http://oreilly.com" + nocache, true)
```

Иначе это выглядит так, буд то у вас должен быть запущен локальный сервер с php.

Comment: Ну так у меня и запущен локальный сервер с пхп, и ajax должен подгружать на страницу, которая лежит на сервере, сайт oreilly.com.
Это ваще-т из книжки пример.